# How to show the lines in a terminal

Tags: shell, terminal

I am using Ubuntu server. When I type, say, "python3 --help", a long list of commands shows. So long that I can't see the lines that were written first. How do I scroll up so that I can see the lines that were displayed first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `less`:

`your_command | less`

Your `Enter` key will take you down.

Also, press `q` to exit.

Comment: Just FYI... `space` will take you down a page-full, `b` will go back a page,  `1G` will take you to the first line, `G` will take you to the last line, `/fred` will take you to a line containing `fred`, `n` will take you to the next occurrence of whatever you last searched for, and `?fred` will search backwards for `fred`.